# Hibernate mapping of two properties to one column

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an object that is generated from XSDs, so I can't change it. In it I have a String DATE and a String TIME (representing the time of day without the date).

DATE = yyyy-mm-dd
TIME = hh:MM:ss:mmmm

In the OracleDB, I don't want to represent these as `VARCHAR`. I'd like to use `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Therefore, I'd need to map both DATE + TIME to one single column, DATETIME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. You can map two columns to a single property (using composites or user types) but not the other way around.

Using the same column name twice in the mapping file usually results in strange exceptions (index out of bounds).

I would use two columns in the database. Convert them to DATE-kind data types using a user type.

Comment: How about creating a field that contains an actual date value based on those two strings and mapping that? Maybe you can subclass your object or perhaps inject such a field?

Comment: I can't. The object is generated from XSDs and the hbm.xml mapping is applied, so it would need to be handled in the hbm.xml. Finally I solved the problem by adding a VIRTUAL column in Oracle : `STARTTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_TIMESTAMP(STARTDATE || ' ' || STARTTIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')) VIRTUAL`